# How to handle one session per tabpage when switching between them

Tags: nhibernate, session, tabpage

I read somewhere that it was a good idea to use a new Session for every Form/Presenter in a C# Desktop application. So I decided to close the session every time the Tab Index changes. Any DB-activity opens a new session.
I have a treeview in each Tab and the Data loads exactly when it should (when the corresponding Node is opened for example)
The only problem is when I leave a Tabpage and a Tree has some opened nodes and then I get back.

There are two different scenarios:

- I click at a leaf node that I already had a look at before I left and revisited that tab
- I click at a leaf node that has never been looked at in that program run (but we can see it because the parent node is expanded)

In the first scenario everything is ok.
In the second scenario I get a LazyInitialization Exception.

1) Can I force the node to Load the data or to remember the data although the sessions is closed?
I don't like the idea that I use only one session for the program.

2) Do you think it might work if I remembered the tree State, collapsed it and reexpanded the necessary nodes? Would it load the data like it did when the user opened it?

Best regards, Expecto

Answer (score 1, accepted):

when you go to a tab with existing data feeding the treeview (which throws the notinitialized exception) reattach it to a newly created session to reenable lazyloading. Use the non obvious `session.Lock(rootentity, LockMode.None);` to reattach the object graph

Comment: great, sounds good. should I reattach the complete treeview or the expanded nodes that make the problem?

Comment: i would reattach the whole treeview because this should be much simpler. the sessions only store references

Comment: currently I have the problem that I don't know how to lock the treeview... I always get a MappingException, which makes sense since the treeview is only a container. I tried to lock each Node seperatly (which contains some mappable object) but that doesn't work either. Am I missing something?

Comment: the error is MappingException No persister for: hyblab.Objects.Product+TreeNodeProduct but I have a mapping for Product, where is "+TreeNodeProduct" coming from?

Comment: "TreeNodeProduct" is a nested Type of product. you have to Lock the mapped objects not the treeview container objects

Comment: Thanks a lot, that did the trick! Sorry for that question I am new to C# and that project I am working on.